# How to document nested and undetermined types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-documentation

I'm trying to document the return type of a function which queries a database. My try goes like this:

```
"""
Execute the query, append a report to the file (start & end time, duration, n rows and result file) and copy results
next to the original file with the same file name but the extension being csv.

:param file_path: file containing a single SQL query
:type file_path: str
:return: data queried from the database
:rtype: {'headers': list<str>, 'rows': list<tuple<any>>}
"""
```

However I'm really not sure about the "rtype".
Here is an example of such an object:

```
{
   "headers": ["id", "name"],
   "rows": [
     (1, "Adrien"),
     (2, "Simon")
   ]
}
```

So it's dict with the key "headers" hosting a list of str and the key "rows" hosting a list of tuples of undetermined type items.
I guess I have two problems here:

1. How to document nested types ? Is `GenericType<SubType>` ok ?
2. How to document an undetermined type ? Is `any` ok ?

I'm looking for convention if any exists.

Comment: isn't this more of a preference question?

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean by "document"? And by "type", do you mean `int`, `str` and other classes?

Comment: @aws_apprentice I don't know, isn't there any convention ?

Comment: @Xteven I mean what should I write at the right of :rtype:, so yes I mean that kind of types. Here I have a dict containing a list of str and a list of list of any type.

Comment: @AdrienH document it as "a dict with a "headers" keys pointing to a list of string and "rows" keys pointing to a list of tuples" (your list of lists should _really_ be a list of tuples - a tuple is not "an immutable list", it's a proper datatype with a completely different semantic)

Comment: Or write a proper data class...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I guess you're right, it's what my cursor returns.